# Create information tooltip about your own methods and classes

Tags: eclipse, class, methods, tooltip, info

My question is very simple. How can you create your own tooltip information for your own created methods and classes, the way all methods and classes of the standard library of java have, when you are writing code and choosing methods and subclasses?!
For example, let's say I have a Class A, in which I have a Method B. Now I define a new instance of Class A in another Class C by writing "A my_class = new A()". Now when I write "my_class.B" I want the Eclipse to show me the information about the Method B in a tooltip, so I know what are the parameters I have to pass to that method B.
Here is a picture example:

[http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/eclipse-javadoc-tooltips100~*v-full*_small.jpg](http://www.subshell.com/en/subshell/blog/eclipse-javadoc-tooltips100~_v-full__small.jpg)

I searched a while, but I didn't find any solutions for that. So maybe you know how to do that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In eclipse, once you add the javadoc comment to your method, it will show up wherever you refer to that method. The Javadoc comment takes the form

```
   /**
    * This is my method description
    * @param x the total number of mangoes allowed
    * @return int the number of litres of juice possible
    */
```

Javadoc comments are placed just before the artifact that it describes. So a method comment will go on the line before the method, a class comment goes on the line before the class statement and so on.

Comment: Ok, your answer was right, but a bit more information would be good :-) the most important would be, that the comment should be outside of the Method or you should say ABOVE THE METHOD!!! :-) thanks for your help -.-